# (goroutine leaks) http.TimeoutHandler does not kill respective ServeHTTP goroutine

Tags: go, httphandler, goroutine, timeoutexception

Timeout handler moves ServeHTTP execution on a new goroutine, but not able to kill that goroutine after the timer ends. On every request, it creates two goroutines, but ServeHTTP goroutines never kill with context.

Not able to find a way to kill goroutines.

**Edit** For-loop with time.Sleep function, represents huge computation which goes beyond our timer. Can replace it with any other function.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "runtime"
    "time"
)

type api struct{}

func (a api) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // For-loop block represents huge computation and usually takes more time
    // Can replace with any code
    i := 0
    for {
        if i == 500 {
            break
        }
        fmt.Printf("#goroutines: %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())
        time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        i++
    }
    _, _ = io.WriteString(w, "Hello World!")
}

func main() {
    var a api
    s := http.NewServeMux()
    s.Handle("/", a)
    h := http.TimeoutHandler(s, 1*time.Second, `Timeout`)

    fmt.Printf("#goroutines: %d\n", runtime.NumGoroutine())

    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8080", h)
}
```

ServeHTTP goroutine should kill along with request context, normally which does not happen.

Comment: go does provide `context.Context` to inform go-routines when to return when a result is no longer needed.

Comment: Go cannot "kill" goroutines, it's up to you to return when the request is done.

Comment: do you agree? It's a leak? I've used time.Sleep to show that its a large time consuming computation and even after request ends it still goes on. Somehow I want to stop that, because there is no meaning of running that goroutine anymore.

Comment: Do we agree with what? Yes it could be considered a leak if you don't return, and it's also invalid to write to the `ResponseWriter` after the request has ended; both of those things are up to you to do correctly.

Comment: Do we agree with what? > about goroutine leak. You already answer that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, if you do not have any way to reach to your channel then there is no way to kill or stop goroutine when it is running.

In the large computational task, you have to watch the channel on a specific interval or after specific task completion.

Answer (score 1):

Use [context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) to instruct go-routines to abort their function. The go-routines, of course, have to listen for such cancelation events.

So for your code, do something like:

```
ctx := req.Context() // this will be implicitly canceled by your TimeoutHandler after 1s

i := 0
for {
    if i == 500 {
        break
    }

    // for any long wait (1s etc.) always check the state of your context
    select {
    case <-time.After(1 * time.Second): // no cancelation, so keep going
    case <-ctx.Done():
        fmt.Println("request context has been canceled:", ctx.Err())
        return // terminates go-routine
    }
    i++
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/VEnW0vsItXm

---

**Note:** `Context` are designed to be chained - allowing for multiple levels of sub-tasks to be canceled in a cascading manner.

In a typical REST call one would initiate a database request. So, to ensure such a blocking and/or slow call completes in a timely manner, instead of using [Query](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.Query) one should use [QueryContext](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.QueryContext) - passing in the http request's context as the first argument.

Comment: Thanks. That means I can never kill any goroutine, if there is a long execution of any task. So, is it good way to use http.TimeoutHandler? Because it creates 2 goroutines?

https://play.golang.org/p/yxjRDxU1eBh

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/ToGlhTA_F9M - fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock! Can you plz help with me? What this error means?

Comment: your linked code has diverged from your original question - perhaps you should post a new question...

Comment: Ok, my original question remains the same. It's a leak and not able to achieve it if there is large computation going on.

Thanks for your help. It is really helpful.